# Get 10 lines from remote url to function

Tags: php, json

I have API which gives me clear 10 IP's of proxy, which I want to use in PAC file in extension to firefox.

This file looks like:

```
1.1.1.1:8080
2.2.2.2:8080
etc. (10 lines = 10 IP's)
```

And I have PAC file, which should like this:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    return "PROXY 4.5.6.7:8080; PROXY 7.8.9.10:8080";
}
```

How do this to print IP from this external rule to this function, like this:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    return "PROXY 1.1.1.1:8080; PROXY 2.2.2.2:8080; PROXY 'line3', PROXY etc....";
}
```

Comment: You can perform a synchronous AJAX call in `FindProxyForURL` and then join the lines into a `;`-separated tring.

Comment: Can you give me some leads how code should look like?

Comment: There are many tutorials on using AJAX. Why should I deprive them of your clicks?

Comment: I trying to understand how it works, but I don't know how to modify examples, which I found there: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp
My code doesn't work at all. This is only what I wan to do, so I thought I will find some helpful person here :)